# Call list by name from loop or lapply, in R

Tags: r, list, call, lapply

I am trying to use the output of a 'by' call which is easily converted to a list... but lists still defy me sometimes

```
a = list('1'=c(19,3,4,5), '4'=c(3,5,3,2,1,6), '8'=c(1,3))

 for (i in c(1,8,4)){
    # would like to do something like this
     a[["i"]]      # calling list elements by name rather than # 
     }


 #ideally the output would be something like this

>19,3,4,5 
>1,3
>3,5,3,2,1,6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List names must character strings; they cannot be numbers.  You need to convert `i` to a character string.  You can use `as.character` or `paste` and you can do it at the initiation of the loop or inside it.

```
a = list('1'=c(19,3,4,5), '4'=c(3,5,3,2,1,6), '8'=c(1,3))

# convert inside loop
for (i in c(1,8,4)) {
  print(a[[as.character(i)]])
}
# convert at initiation
for (i in as.character(c(1,8,4))) {
  print(a[[i]])
}
```

Comment: @user1034797 -- If Joshua's answer was exactly what you needed, don't forget to 'accept' it by clicking the checkmark to its left.  Thanks.

Comment: Another possibility could be `for (i in names(a)) {...`

Comment: @Marek: I didn't even think of that. I guess I was thinking the list would have more elements than the one the OP wanted to loop over.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looping over the elements of the list to do something with each element (I realize you example is simplified), then consider the apply family of functions which do just this:

```
lapply(a, print)
```

Things get printed twice when entered interactively because they are printed inside the `lapply`, and then the return value of `lapply` is printed.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over list without indexing:

```
for (ai in a) {
    print(ai)
}
```

It's good unless you need name of the element.